# resizing an external application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, resize

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim s As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Hide()
        Try
            Dim objectreader As New System.IO.StreamReader("execany.ini")
            Try

                s = objectreader.ReadLine()
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s)
                objectreader.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("File not found" & " " & s, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Ini file not found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Me.Close()

        End Try



        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have this code and I want to resize the file that opens when I call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` I do not want it to open maximized.

For example a pdf file: I want it to open in the middle and restored down not maximized nor minimized. I have searched threads they all refer to an api but no function seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're using `Process.Start` directly. While doing this is easy to do, you can go just a little bit deeper and achieve *exactly* what you want to do.

The [ProcessStartInfo class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to specify parameters normally not achievable with just `Process.Start`.

Part of these parameters comes `WindowState` - which is exactly what you need.

Take this, for example:

```
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("FileName")
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
```

This will start `FileName` with a normal window state. You can choose from `Hidden`, `Maximized`, `Minimized` and `Normal` window states.

As a side-note, it's worthwhile looking into the class as it has many handy features.

Comment: thank you Alex for responding , i have tried that but still it wont give me what i need and when i put the normal it still opens full size for example a pdf file , what i want is for it to open in the middle of the screen and not full sized.i have been searching for it and found few methods but they just wont work and they all use user32.dll..any help will be appreciated

Comment: Then your PDF reader is setting itself to maximized, meaning whatever you do with `Process` won't have an effect, as you know. Try [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos), then.